# RN FCM & in-app (foreground) banner notifications

Tags: react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

See title: how to implement in-app (foreground) banner notifications with React Native Firebase Cloud Messaging?

I got it to work with the 'Alert' module but this pops up in the middle of your screen whereas I would want just a banner on the top of the screen that does not interfere with the user's actions.

```
messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
  // Set the matchScreenParentState to 'loading' in case the message 'type' property specifies new match
  // Notifications for chats don't trigger anything. That will be just socket.io
  if (remoteMessage.data.notificationType==='matchFound') {
    setMatchScreenParentState('loading')
    Alert.alert('A new match was found!')
  }
})
```

Looking at the documentation it shows that there are no notifications when app is in foreground but surely such a core feature must be available somehow??? https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#notifications